# How do I return the value of the class <div> without returning the value of the <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I return the value of "Jhon Doe" without the "x"

https://jsfiddle.net/sok1hkkt/3/

```
<div class="chip"><span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.remove()">&times;</span>John Doe</div>
<script>
var array = $( ".chip" )
  .map(function() {
    return this.textContent; //changeing only this line
  })
  .get()
  .join(); 
  alert(array)
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sok1hkkt/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
// Take the whole inner HTML, split it at the span closing tag,
// take the second element which is the desired text
var text= $( ".chip" ).html().split('</span>')[1];
alert(text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sok1hkkt/4/

If you need it for multiple elements, you can use the [jQuery .each() function](https://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

```
var array = [];

$( ".chip" ).each(function(){
    array.push($(this).html().split('</span>')[1]);
});

alert(array);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sok1hkkt/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
var getText =$('.chip').clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

      alert(getText);
```

Answer (score 1):

can we do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/sok1hkkt/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = $(".chip")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();    ;
  alert(array);

});
```